# Update the permissions of a space and make it read-only using the Confluence Cloud REST API

Tags: cloud, confluence-rest-api

I would like to know how to use the Confluence Cloud REST API to update the permissions of a space and set it as read-only for all users and groups. Is there a specific approach or endpoint that can help achieve this? Your guidance and insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!